# bitrix export/import инфоблоков

Tags: база-данных, битрикс

задача перенести инфоблок с одного сайта на другой, с обязательным сохранением разделов (инфоблок товаров без разделов никуда не годится))
для простоты использую модуль из маркета экспорт\импорт который предлагает на выбор xml или csv. csv копирует без разделов. в xml есть возможность сохранение разделов, НО импортировать xml не получается( пишет что импорт завершен, добавлено 0, при нажатии "перейти к списку элементов" кидает на авторизацию админки и пишет Ошибка авторизации!
Неверный тип блока.
нашел что type= не прописан, прописал, это не помогло)
подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить)

Comment: а чем штатный не устроил, что пришлось в маркет лезть? все отлично работает.

Comment: и не помешала бы точная ссылка на модуль из маркета

Comment: да это все уже не важно, проблема была с импортом в xml, редко где можно найти что для импорта кроме файла создается папка с файлами. После открытия этой "тайны" все стало на свои места.

Answer (score 1):

При экспорте в xml создается папка с файлами, которая должна лежать в одной папке с файлом импорта для корректной работы.